# How to trigger ngchange event when user pastes something in a content editable div using mouse right click?

Tags: angularjs

I've a content editable div and when user pastes something in it using Mouse Right Click and Paste, I want to trigger a function. I already have ng-change event bound so if I can trigger that, that's also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood well, but to trigger `paste` *events* you can use [**`ngPaste`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPaste) directive.

Here's an **example**:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
      alert('Yes, it works');
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-paste="doSomething()" placeholder="Paste here">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't trigger when user pastes using contextmenu (right click mouse + Paste)

Comment: Ah! sorry for not being clear.
What I meant is that it doesn't trigger on content editable div.

Comment: Add some example in your question please.

Comment: The code I have is a part of a bigger thing but I tried to isolate that part here in this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/cy7ehwy3/1/

What I don't get with ng-paste is what user actually pasted.
Looks like it get triggered before value is actually added to the editable div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-paste` for this

```
<input ng-paste="paste=true" ng-init="paste=false" placeholder='paste here'>
```

You can take watch on that `$scope.paste` OR call a function on `ng-paste` as

`<input ng-paste="getPastedText(pastedText)" ng-model="pastedText" placeholder='paste here'>`

The main problem with ng-paste is it will call the function `getPastedText` when ever you are pasting something but **will not give an idea if you clear the input**

Comment: What's the difference of my answer?

Comment: @developer033 sorry dude, I haven't seen that.